# Fading in a div on a single page without calculating from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I'm really curious about this situation. I have a single page, and every page scrolled down has height of 1080px, but I can't calculate properly the scrollTop degree..

When I use  a small monitor it fades in before div enters the monitor

```
$(window).scroll( function() {

    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 300 ) {

       loadDiv2(); /* calls loadDiv2 Function below */
    }
});

function loadDiv2() {
    $('#hakkimizda').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. Also the code for `loadDiv2` looks strange: it fades `#hakkimizda` in (making it visible), and when the animation completes, it fades the element opacity to 1 (it's already visible from the `fadeIn`, so users won't notice anything)

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code, thanks a lot.

```js
function scrollfadein(selector, offset)
{
    $(selector)
    .css('opacity', 0)
    .each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        var fun = function()
        {
            offset = (offset == undefined) ? 0 : (offset < 1 ? offset*el.height() : offset);
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() > el.offset().top - $(window).height() + offset )
            {
                el.animate({'opacity':1},1500);
                $(window).off('scroll', fun);
            }
        };
        $(window).on('scroll', fun);
    });
}

scrollfadein('#hakkimizda,#yil_wrap', 0.3);
scrollfadein('#baklava', 0.9);
scrollfadein('#baklava_2', 0.5);
scrollfadein('#baklava_3', 0.9);


});
```